# redeploying istio...galley errors out

Tags: istio

I had an instance of istio running fine via helm:

`helm template --set kiali.enabled=true --set grafana.enabled=true install/kubernetes/helm/istio --name istio --namespace istio-system > $HOME/istio.yaml`

during some unrelated issues, I had to nuke the istio namespace (`kubectl delete ns istio-system`)

however, after deleting ns, and redoing the istio install, Galley seems to be erroring out:

which in turn puts both istio-policy and istio-telemtry in a crash loop.

The logs for galley says:

```
 fatal   Invalid validationArgs: 1 error occurred:
    * port number 443 must be in the range 1024..65535
```

whats a possible solution?

Comment: have you tried killing the galley pod only to see if when it re-starts the issue is gone? IF the issue is gone, kill the other two pods too.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be that you need to perform an clean up for the whole Istio installation.
Please try uninstalling Istio on GKE and start from the scratch.

[Uninstalling Istio on GKE](https://cloud.google.com/istio/docs/istio-on-gke/uninstalling)